# OR-Tools: compare lists in solver maximize

Tags: or-tools

Lets say I have 2 lists: `list_1` and `list_2` of the same size containing Bool variables

```
list_1 = [ model.NewBoolVar('var1'), ..., model.NewBoolVar('var9')]

list_2 = [ model.NewBoolVar('var10'), ..., model.NewBoolVar('var19') ]
```

I then add other constraints and I finally want to maximize so that to 2 lists should be the most alike. I have though of doing of sum of the XNor result between each elements of both lists but I do not know how to do this? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use enforced linear constraints.

```
bi => xi == yi
bi.not() => xi != yi
```

Then sum of bi